# Why ACTION_CALL not working on Android 11

Tags: android, android-intent, call, phone-call, android-phone-call

Why does this sentence ( **to place a call enter a valid number** ) appear when I run this code?

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "#1234#"));
                startActivity(intent);
```

But if you change the number from **"#1234#"** to **"123456789"** it works without problems
Why is the (**#**) symbol not accepted?

Knowing that I added

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

Note: It still works in versions less than **Android 11** and accepts the (**#**) symbol without problems.

Comment: I found the solution

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ Uri.encode("#1234#")));
                startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried replacing "#" with "%"?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("#1234#")));
startActivity(intent);
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: welcome Sir
You did not understand what I meant
I want to create a button when the user clicks on it
Dial directly to this number (**#1234#**)
Because this number (**#1234#**), if the user calls it in my country, he knows how many minutes are left at the telecom operator (Vodafone) (SIM).

Comment: Yes I did understand, and replacing those characters that way does that you're asking for. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried and it didn't work

Comment: I found the solution

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ Uri.encode("#1234#")));
                startActivity(intent);

Comment: Awesome! I've updated the answer for future readers!